# How to use Handlebars in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, handlebars.js, handlebars.java

I have the packages, but I am not sure how to use it. Do I just use them as I would .jsp files?

I have tried something like this:

**test.hbs**

```
<p>{{message}}</p>
```

in my controller:

```
private static class M {
    private final String message;

    public M(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView testView() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("test.hbs");
    M m = new M("Hello, world!");

    mav.addObject("m", m);

    return mav;
}
```

I am getting the error: **javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'test.hbs' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'**

I have put **test.hbs** normally in /WEB-INF/views/test.hbs. If I put any .jsp file there, it works. But from some reason .hbs doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring MVC does not have out-of-the-box support for Handlebars (see [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view) for the list of supported view technologies).

Having said that, it is straightforward to add support for any JVM based view technology to Spring MVC. At a high level, this requires implementing a `org.springframework.web.servlet.View` and its corresponding `org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver`.

Luckily, there already exists [an open source project](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/tree/master/handlebars-springmvc) that provides this integration. The following steps can be followed to integrate this project in an existing Spring MVC application.

> **Step 1**: Add the library to the build system (assuming Maven)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.jknack</groupId>
  <artifactId>handlebars-springmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

> **Step 2**: Configure a Handlebars `ViewResolver` for the Spring MVC application in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (or equivalent Java configuration)

```
<bean class="com.github.jknack.handlebars.springmvc.HandlebarsViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".hbs"/>
</bean>
```

> **Step 3**: Add Handlebars views to the application

Given the configuration above, Handlebars views should be added under the `/WEB-INF/views/` folder.

> **Step 4**: Load Handlebars views

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView testView() {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("test");
  M m = new M("Hello, world!");

  mav.addObject("m", m);

  return mav;
}
```

Note that the view name should not contain `.hbs` as the suffix has already been added to the configuration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation - however I need that in Spring MVC 4 (with annotations and not the XML). I know how to create such bean, but how do you add dependency?

Comment: The dependency needs to be added to your build file (Maven or Gradle). The code will work with Spring 3/4 alike. XML and annotations based configurations are equivalent so just translate the XML snippets to Java. If you don't know how, consult the official Spring documentation which shows side-by-side examples for both and learn from that.

Comment: For Spring 5 the list of supported view technologies is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view